# Why is my JsPdf shoving all elements to the left and making their width small?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

When I use jsPDF to generate a pdf of my site, all the elements are shoved to the left and as thin as they can be.  I've tried setting width in both the `pdf.html()` options as well as the html2canvas options inside.

```js
    const doc = new jsPDF({
        orientation: "p",
        format: "legal",
        unit: "px",
        hotfixes: ["px_scaling"]
    });

    const elementHandler = {
        '#ignorePDF': function (element) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    const body = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
    
    doc.html(body.parentElement, {
        autoPaging: 'text',
        width: 1000,
        html2canvas: {
            width: 1000,
            windowWidth: 1000
        },
        callback: async function (doc) {
            doc.setLineWidth(1000);
            doc.save("test.pdf")
        },
        elementHandler: elementHandler
    });
```

This generates a pdf that looks like this:

[image: messed up pdf]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
const width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();

doc.html(body.parentElement, {
    autoPaging: 'text',
    width: width,
    windowWidth: width,
    callback: async function (doc) {
        doc.save("test.pdf")
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).